# How to use alias in like using mysql or sql lite

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select name , count(name) c from user where name like '%a%' or c like '%9';
```

But here i am getting error while using alias in query.

How i can use the count in like

Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Try moving the "c like" condition into HAVING.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use HAVING for aliases

```
SELECT name AS n , count(name) c 
FROM user 
HAVING n LIKE '%a%' OR c like '%9';
```

Comment: Wonderful, how could I miss this.. :-) 
+1 for thinking this :-)

Comment: I need to use or condition how i can use this

Comment: if you are using GROUP BY then make sure to write it before HAVING i.e. WHERE .... GROUP BY .... HAVING

Comment: Set alias n for name and then you have  HAVING n like '%a%' OR c like %9 :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39654/discussion-between-psr-and-jerko-w-tisler)

Answer (score -1):

In MYSQL **you cannot use the alias here in the where clause**.
You can use that in `GROUP BY`

```
select 
name , 
count(name) c 
from user 
where name like '%a%' and count(name) like '%9';
```

OR IF You want to use the alias you can try WITH `HAVING` as Jereko and Joe has suggested